# Excel Pivot Table Calculated Field Syntax Issue

Tags: excel

I'm trying to use calculated field to substract the difference between 2014 and 2013, and then 2015 and 2014. As you can see on the right of this picture I have year in columns which displays years 2013-2015.

When I try to set up the formula for calculated field I'm not sure what the syntax is. On most problems and in the documentation for excel I've seen it done as "Year - 'some value'".  But I don't have fields like 2013 or 2014 for me to use in the formula?

Any help on how I could write the syntax to solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: You need a calculated item, not a calculated field. Or you can simply change the ROE field to use 'Show values As', 'difference from previous'

Comment: @Rory Thanks. That was it.